# Simple Login System using CodeIgniter returning 404 on login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get my head around `PHP` and using the `CodeIgniter` Framework. I have recently been following this tutorial:

http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

I went through it very methodically and was careful to ensure I made no errors in writing the code. However when I run my project in a browser I get this error after I attempt to submit my login details.

**Not Found
The requested URL /LoginTut/login/VerifyLogin was not found on this server.**

I ran into a similar problem not to long ago when I was following another tutorial and could not figure it out so abandoned the project.

This is how I configured my CI

**routes.php**

`$route['default_controller'] = "login";`

**config.php**

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/LoginTut/';`

I left this blank.

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

I've also ensure I am loading all relevant libraries and helpers.

**autoload.php**

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Below are all of my PHP files..

**user.php**

```
class User extends CI_Model{
function login($username, $password){
    $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
    $this -> db -> from ('users');
    $this -> db -> where ('username', $username);
    $this -> db -> where ('password', md5($password));
    $this -> db -> limit(1);

    $query = $this  -> db -> get();

    if($query -> num_rows() == 1){
        retrun $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

**login_view.php**

```
   <?php echo form_open('VerifyLogin'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
```

**login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

verify_login.php

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller{

function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->model('user', '', TRUE);
}

function index(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Validation failed, user redirected to login page...
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else{
        //Login success. Go to members only area
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}

function check_database($password){
    //Field validation succeeded. Validate against db
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    //query db
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result){
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row){
            $sess_array = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'username' => $row->username
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

The user should be able to successfully log in and end up at the `home.php` controller which loads the `home_view.php` file.

This is the Post action of the login form

```
http://localhost/LoginTut/login/VerifyLogin
```

I would really appreciate any help relating to this issue, I've been struggling with it for days now and It's starting to really annoy me. I've a feeling It's something very small going wrong within my code. I just don't have enough knowledge to figure it out.

NOTE: I read in a forum it could be something to do with a .htaccess problem, but I've no idea what that is!

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess`file in place? If not, add one to the root of your CI-install, that looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827335/cannot-find-mod-rewrite-for-codeigniter/14828424#14828424

Comment: @Mudshark Checked my `.htacces` file. It is in the root folder and it's contents are this `deny from all`. I imagine this is not ideal? Should I paste the code in the link you provided into this file?

Comment: No joy unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you put it in `http://localhost/LoginTut/` (which you should) ? `deny from all`is something I'd expect inside the `application`folder's `htaccess`.

Comment: No I did not. I changed it now. I included the contents of the file in my question. I am still getting error!

Comment: Must be more to it than the htaccess issue then. Don't have time to review your full code right now :\

Comment: Put some echo statements in your VerifyLogin#index method to see where the code gets before failing. I would start by checking if the code gets inside the "if" or the "else" in your VerifyLogin#index method.

Comment: It doesn't even enter the index() method

Comment: If i was you, i would remove the .htaccess file for now and put 'index.php' back in the `$config['index_page']`. Then you'll be able to tell if it's an .htaccess issue or an issue with the code in your app.

Comment: i face same problem ..PLEASE ** HELP **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered your other post as well, but just to reiterate:

You named your controller "verify_login.php" but your class is named "VerifyLogin". In Codeigniter your class needs to be named the same as your file, just with capital letters. In order for that page to work correctly you should either rename your controller file to "verifyLogin.php" or rename your class to "Verify_Login".

Comment: I have the same problem but i can't fix it. maybe it is with my routes. but i copied the .htacces file from javacadabra. and that one works. so that isn't the problem.

Comment: EDIT: when i edit the line    <?php echo form_open('verify_login'); ?> to    <?php echo form_open('owrb'); ?> (this is my homepage) it routes to that. but it doesn't to verify_login. then i get an 404

Comment: @KeesSonnema - Please read my response here. Javacadabra's issue was caused by not naming his controller the same as his class. Do you have that issue as well? If not, did you name your class "Verify_login" or "Verify_Login"?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off rewrite for a while. First fix this with the normal CodeIgniter URLs:

CodeIgniter URLs work like this:

```
<base_url>/<index-page>/<controller>/<methodOfController>/<parameters>
```

When you requested `.../login/VerifyLogin` that will not work because both *login* and *VerifyLogin* are controllers. CodeIgniter will "think" that you want to call the method *VerifyLogin()* in the controller class *login*. You should instead call `.../VerifyLogin/index`.

You left `$config['index_page']` empty. In CodeIgniter you cannot call methods on controllers directly; you have do let CodeIgniter do it for you. This means CodeIgniter has to run first and will then parse the URL and delegate the request to the correct controller and method. That is what the config *index_page* is for - to start CodeIgniter. You have to run **all** requests through this file.

There is an *index.php* included in CodeIgniter (it ends with the line `require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';`). Use this one as index_page.

When you've done this your complete URL will be this:

```
http://localhost/LoginTut/index.php/VerifyLogin/index/<parameters>
```

Comment: ` <?php echo form_open('../VerifyLogin/index'); ?>` is giving me the same error? Your answer is very helpful though. Any idea why this is not working? Could it be to do with the fact that I named my controller file `verify_login.php` and called the class `VerifyLogin` ?

Comment: @Javacadabra: Yes (i missed that, sorry). Class and file have to have the same name.

Comment: i get a page index.php written